# Executing certain code from a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

Here is some code which loops through an area in a spreadsheet and executes the code based on the condition that the source cells do not contain the value "(blank)".

The code works, but it's very inefficient to run nested `if` statements in this manner.  I've tried to have a go at making it more efficient in the long run but I'm out of ideas.

Any suggestions?

```
Sub NestedIfStatement()
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim I As Integer, J As Integer, N As Integer, MaxPriority as Integer

N = 3
Set Maxnumber = WS1.Range("A" & I & ":A" & lastrow1)
    MaxPriority = Application.Max(Maxnumber)

For J = 1 To lastrow1
    If WS1.Cells(J, 1) <= MaxPriority Then
       If WS1.Cells(J, 6).Value <> "(blank)" Then
          WS3.Cells(N, 7).Value = WS1.Cells(J, 6).Value
       End If
       If WS1.Cells(J, 5).Value <> "(blank)" Then
          WS3.Cells(N, 6).Value = WS1.Cells(J, 5).Value
       End If
       If WS1.Cells(J, 4).Value <> "(blank)" Then
          WS3.Cells(N, 4).Value = WS1.Cells(J, 4).Value
       End If
       If WS1.Cells(J, 3).Value <> "(blank)" Then
          WS3.Cells(N, 3).Value = WS1.Cells(J, 3).Value
       End If
       If WS1.Cells(J, 2).Value <> "(blank)" Then
          WS3.Cells(N, 2).Value = WS1.Cells(J, 2).Value
       End If
       N = N + 1
    End If
Next J

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggestion #1: Use `Option Explicit` and/or use fewer global variables**

Either `MaxNumber, MaxPriority` are never explicitly defined, which is a **very** bad idea and is why you should use `Option Explicit`, or they're Global Variables, which is redundant, because they're self-contained within this subroutine.

**Suggestion #2: Don't work directly with worksheet ranges**

Accessing a worksheet is **slow**. You don't notice because doing it once is almost-instant, but do it a thousand times and it starts adding up really fast.

Whenever I'm working with worksheet data, the **first** thing I do is read all of it into an Array:

```
Dim wsData As Variant
    wsData = Array()

Dim dataTable As Range
Set dataTable = "" '/ Define your worksheet range

    ReDim arrWsData(1 To Rows, 1 To columns)  '/ Same size as the range

    wsData = dataTable
```

Now you have a 2-dimensional array, with all your worksheet data laid out in exactly the same way as it was on the sheet. Excel can iterate over an Array **orders of magnitude faster** than over a range because it doesn't have to access the worksheet object every time.

You can print an array to a sheet by doing the same in reverse: Define your range to be the same size as your array. Range = Array.

**Suggestion #3: Recursion**

Assuming you put the range `A1:F50` from WS1 in an array, you can now iterate over it like so:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
Dim testValue As Variant

Dim printData As Variant
    printData = Array()

ReDim printData(1 To lastRow, 1 To 5)

For j = 1 To lastRow
    If wsData(j, 1) <= MaxPriority Then
        n = n + 1
        For i = 1 To 5
            testValue = wsData(j, i + 1)
            If testValue <> "(blank)" Then printData(j, i) = testValue
        Next i
    End If
Next j
```

you can now change the size of your data, or the progression of the sequence, or a whole host of other things by changing 1 or 2 numbers. And 20 lines of code just became 4.

You can now pick any range on WS3 and print your output data there.

I don't know why your output columns on WS3 Jump a column from 6 to 4, but you can always write specific parts of your array to specific parts of the output sheet if needed.

**Suggestion #4: Meaningful Variable Names**

What is `WS1`? What is `WS3`? I know they're worksheets, but which worksheets? They appear next to each other in multiple places in this subroutine. If you accidentally put a 1 instead of a 3 somewhere, you can't tell at a glance where you've gone wrong. **Give your variables names**

Even a simple `wsInput`, `wsOutput` would be **so** much better.

`MaxNumber` Sounds like it should be, well, a number. Except it's a range. **variables should say what they are**. Even if that means writing `VariableThatHoldsThisThing`, it'll save you **so** much time down the road in debugging and maintaining and less technical debt.

Here, I recommend something like `dataTable<description>` (I don't know the context of your data, so you can think of a much more succinct name yourself).

On the other side, `MaxPriority` is a **good** variable name. It holds a number which represents the maximum priority from some table of priority numbers.

Also `NestedIfStatement` is a **terrible** procedure name. It tells me nothing about what the procedure does. Procedure names should be of the form `<DoThing>` or `Perfom<Action>On<Thing>` or any larger combination thereof. If you can't describe your procedure in a (reasonably) short name, then it's a good sign that it's trying to do too much, and should be split into several smaller procedures.